# When should you NOT use event delegation?

Tags: javascript, performance, delegation

Generally, you should always delegate a group of elements to a parent, but was curious if at any point its more costly perf wise to use it, or, when is it *really* needed? Is delegating 10 handlers really saving that much perf? 100? 1000? At what point should I take the time of figuring out how to delegate events to parent views. Since views are independent and don't know about parent views, delegating isn't trivial, so curious what exactly the performance gains I get in modern browsers doing this.

Comment: Then create some benchmarks/performance-profiles of *your* use-case. At which point does it work out better for *you*? Do any "performance" differences even matter? If not then, trivially, use the cleaner approach.

Comment: You hardly ever *need* it. You will notice when you do need it. [Don't prematurely optimize.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization) Maybe interesting reading: [Moving from classic event management to event delegation in JavaScript OOP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18680295/1048572)

Comment: @user2864740 Im looking for overall strategies and patterns. As in, "if it's any less than N handlers then you probably don't need it". Information to bring to all projects.

Comment: If you don't have a performance problem (which will be *indicated* with a performance benchmark/profile), you don't *need* (or not need) delegation. Consider how many projects/sites don't use a single delegate - without any "performance" issues. Delegation should be used if/when it allows the problem to be approached cleaner, generally not for "performance" reasons.

Comment: delegation is nice when you have many elements, especially temporary elements in a predictable hierarchy, such as a grid or fancy list. If you just have a simple form you want to jazz up, there's no need. the trend these days is moving toward inline events over off-sides binding, even it's called ngclick instead of onclick...

Answer (score 0):

When you just want perform event operation on some portions of the elements. Then you use event delegation.

**But if you want to skip event operation on some portion then you should not use event delegation.**

You can stop propagation by

```js
$('form#global_search_ajax_post_form').delegate('.global-category-list li a', 'click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();  
});
```