# <autofocus> unable to get focus repeatedly until the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a footnote at the bottom of an article to annotate following up status;

```
<article class="col-md-12">
</article>
<div class="col-md-12 footnote">
    <a href="{% url 'article:footnote_add'%}">add a footnote</a>
</div>
```

When the "add a footnote" link is hidden after being clicked and prompt the "footnote form" which I set `autofocus` which `textarea`. The "autofucus" works properly.

```
$('.footnote-link a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    var $footnoteForm = $(`
<form class="article-footnote-form footnote-form" style="margin-top:10px" >
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="footnote" rows="3" autofocus></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="articleFootnoteBtn">Add Annotation</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>`);
     $articleFootnoteLink.parent().hide();
     $articleFootnoteLink.parent().after($footnoteForm);
```

The form is submitted to server using Ajax then I cleared the forms by

`$footnotesTop.find(".footnote-form").html("")`. Now the page displays the article and the newly added footnote.

However, if I click the "add footnote" again, it unable to get focus automatically as it does at first time until I refresh the page to click.

How could I get the form focus during the second click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a delegated eventHandler. The js code `$('.footnote-link a').on('click', function (e) {` is only applied to the elements jQuery finds using that selector when the page is loaded.

Try `$( document ).on('click', '.footnote-link a', function (e) {`. You can use a tighter selector rather than document - it seems like `.footnote` would work based on what I see.

[jQuery delegated events tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thank you, Is it a common practice always employed $(body) or $(document) rather than specified selectors?

Comment: No, not really. There could potentially be some lag for pages with a lot of dynamically added content and a lot of event handlers. If you have an inkling that you will be modifying the dom and you know there won't be a ton of elements on the page then the practice is okay. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922305/are-there-performance-drawbacks-to-using-a-delegated-event-handler-in-javascript